# Chrome splitting sections on page break, works on firefox perfectly

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have an issue with chrome that i could't figure out yet.
I followed many posts here and searched around but they didn't help.
My chrome version is 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit) and presumably the user's version will be too.

page-break-inside: avoid; doesn't work at all.
all the elements from body up to the smallest sections are all set to position:relative and float:none

but supposing I have something like this:

```css
 .row{
        page-break-inside: avoid;
  position: relative;
    }

 .break-after {
  display: block;
  page-break-after: always;
  position: relative;
 }
```

```html
<section class="row first"></section>
<section class="row second break-after"></section>
<section class="row third"></section>
<section class="row fourth"></section>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

Depending on the size of the content of the sections, chrome might still cut the third or fourth row in half, firefox doesn't do this and works perfectly.

Any tips?

Thanks in advance, you guys are awesome.

Comment: your code snippet doesn't show a good example of the issue.

Comment: Sorry, that is because the original code it hundred's of lines long...

Comment: maybe this image will help? http://imgur.com/a/U4E5F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was elements with negative margins.